# How do I use a delimiter with Scanner.useDelimiter in Java to delimeter [,?

Tags: java, string

want to use delimer for [, in the same delimter.

if the text for example is: [7,(-1-5i)]

so to make a delimiter for [, so I can separate the 7 as a intger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` character, which is has a special meaning in a regex:

```java
myScanner.useDelimiter("[\\[,]");
```